# Will Ubuntu Brick my Samsung Series 5?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, samsung

I bought a Samsung Series 5 in South Korea in 2013, model number NT550P7C (NT550P7C-S86). I've read on several older posts ([here](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2013/02/01/linux_samsung_laptop_fix_advice/),
 for example) that Ubuntu can cause the motherboard on some Samsung laptops to brick, particularly those shipped with windows 8, as this one was. I am interested in dual booting windows 8.1 and Ubuntu, but don't want to run the risk of ruining my laptop. Does anyone know for sure if this is safe? Or is there another safe way to do it? Thank you.

Comment: Please include specifications of this Laptop. I have never heard of the term brick in conjunction with an Intel based laptop given you can always reinstall the OS, unlike on phones or tablets. But given this is a Samsung device I don't want to be absolute...

Comment: Please give us a link or something to support your claim that Ubuntu has been known to brick laptops. I've never heard of such a thing and have trouble imagining how it could be possible.

Comment: @terdon Ubuntu really is known to brick some laptops because of UEFI bugs. I bricked one myself, but could recover it. It is not a linux fault. The OP's laptop may be affected.

Comment: @Pilot6 oh wow. Yes, I found an article explaining it and added it to the OP.  What an insane bug!

Comment: The UEFI bug is really insane. I can't imagine who wrote that stupid code. I had to recover UEFI manually.

Answer (score 4):

It is not safe to boot from an Ubuntu LiveUSB in UEFI mode on Samsung laptops.

Samsung UEFI had a bug that could brick the laptop.

If you switch off "UEFI Boot" in BIOS settings, it should be safe.

I bought a similar Samsung laptop in 2014 and installed Ubuntu in legacy mode with no problems. Then after I read that there was a commit with a workaround, I tried to re-install Ubuntu in UEFI mode last year.

I could successfully boot in UEFI mode and install Ubuntu. But after grub was installed, the UEFI was ruined and it was not possible to boot any OS except booting from DVD. USB boot didn't work.

I could find a firmware (that was very hard because Samsung doesn't make firmware available for download) and a Windows flashing utility, then I found a hack how to flash with resetting NAND memory. I did it using Live WindowsPE image.

I won't do it again, becuase it was a pure luck to find a flashable firmware because the firmware doesn't let to reflash or reset the existing firmware. I found a bit newer release for a similar (not exactly same) laptop.

Otherwise I would have to solder out the flash and restore it manually.

Comment: Are you sure this is still an issue? I found an [article](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2013/02/01/linux_samsung_laptop_fix_advice/) from 2003 which stated the kernel had already been modified then to deal with this Samsung flaw. It's now 4 years later, why would it still be an issue?

Comment: I am sure, I tested it myself after the kernel was updated. It is still an issue because Samsung never released firmware updates and stopped producing regular laptops. I was curious and bricked an old laptop. It was produced in 2014.